# Proof of the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition through the Wedderburn-Malcev theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I encountered an application of Wedderburn-Malcev's theorem in proving the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition. I am asking for clarification on a step of the proof attached below, namely

"the image of $x$ generates $A/J\cong B$; thus $x_s$ is semisimple and a polynomial of $x$."

I do not understand why $x_s$ is a polynomial in $x$. Since $A/J\cong B$ and $A=F[x]$, every element of $A/J$ has a coset representative of the form $p(x)\in F[x]$. However, I only see from this that $x_s$ is a polynomial in $x$ modulo the radical.

> **Wikipedia, *"Jordan–Chevalley decomposition"*:**

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a perfect field $k$, $x : V \to V$ an endomorphism and $A = k[x] \subset \operatorname{End}(V)$ the subalgebra generated by $x$. Note that $A$ is a commutative Artinian ring. The Wedderburn principal theorem states: for a finite-dimensional algebra $A$ with the Jacobson radical $J$, if $A/J$ is separable, then the natural surjection $p: A \to A/J$ splits; i.e., $A$ contains a semisimple subalgebra $B$ such that $p|_B : B \overset{\sim} \to A/J$ is an isomorphism. In the setup here, $A/J$ is separable since the base field is perfect (so the theorem is applicable) and $J$ is also the nilradical of $A$. There is then the vector-space decomposition $A = B \oplus J$. In particular, the endomorphism $x$ can be written as $x = x_s + x_n$ where $x_s$ is in $B$ and $x_n$ in $J$. Now, **the image of $x$ generates $A/J \simeq B$; thus $x_s$ is semisimple and is a polynomial of $x$**. Also, $x_n$ is nilpotent since $J$ is nilpotent and is a polynomial of $x$ since $x_s$ is. $\square$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = F[x] = B \oplus J$ means that *every* element of $A$ (and thus $B \oplus J$) is a polynomial in $x$, and in particular that is true for every element $w \in B \oplus 0$. Then just take $x_s$ from $B \oplus 0$ that is equal to $x$ modulo $J$.